# My is my modal only working for the first image in gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page has a gallery with lots of pictures, and I've been able to set up a modal using js and css to show an enlarged image on click. However, while my fist image works as expected, my others don't.

I used [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) from W3Schools to make it.

Here's what it should look like.
[image]

This is my HTML:

```
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close" title="Close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-window">
      <img
        src=".//assets/carina-nebula.jpg"
        class="img"
        id="myImg"
        alt="Carina Nebula"
        title="Click to enlarge"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="img-window">
      <img
        src=".//assets/tarantula-nebula.png"
        class="img"
        id="myImg"
        title="Click to enlarge"
      />
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 80%;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. I.e. you can't repeat `id="myImg"`

Comment: The id must be unique... i'll suggest to not use w3school site because often is outdated... better use for example [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("myImg")` will always give you the very first DOM element. ID is used for one element in HTML.

Because you have multiple items you want to add click, use another method like `document.querySelectorAll(".img")` to get all elements that will return `nodeList`. You have to loop over elements and attach `addEventListener` to each element and pass img attribute to the function.

```js
function openDialogueBox(img) {
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = img.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      openDialogueBox(e.target)
  });
});
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 80%;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close" title="Close">&times;</span>
    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />
    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="img-window">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" class="img"
        alt="Carina Nebula" title="Click to enlarge" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-window">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/268533/pexels-photo-268533.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-268533.jpg&fm=jpg"
        alt="Carina Nebula two" class="img" title="Click to enlarge" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise with an explanation.

Comment: @Kameron, i got it while you put comments, that time adding explanation.

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be **unique**, so if you want to do something to multiple elements in Javascript, you must get them with a different method. I suggest you to use `getElementsByClassName`.

The following example is based on your code.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("img"); // Here we get all the elements with the class "img"
// ... //

for (const img of images) { // With this for loop we make an action with every element in the "images" variable.
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```